# C# DLL Import attribute source code?

Tags: c#, attributes, dllimport

Anyone know how to make an attribute in C# that will work for an external function?

I need to write an attribute to import shared objects (This is NOT for windows, I am developing a kernel in C# using a project called Cosmos, I recently finished my ELF32 loader and dynamic linker and which to write an attribute that will do this)

```
[SOImport("/lib/screen.so")]
extern void print(string text);
```

I have never really had to write my own attribute before, but I looked up some tutorials and could not find anything relating to external methods. I am assuming it returns some sort function pointer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need your own compiler for that.

Comment: DLLImport was written in C#, its not 'built in' to the language.

Comment: Do you want the attribute to execute, or do you just need the metadata?

Comment: I need it to execute, I already have a method I wrote to invoke a function from an ELF file and that works just fine.

Comment: @user1454902, the DllImport attribute was indeed probably written in C#, but it doesn't do anything itself, it's just metadata. It's the compiler that uses it to emit the proper marshalling code.

Comment: Oh really? Ok i'll just stick to my invoke function then.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Actually, I suspect that happens in the CLR.

Comment: @SLaks It would appear that is the case.. the generated IL doesn't do anything particularly special except mark them with a `pinvokeimpl`. Interesting stuff! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `SOImport` attribute would function like the `DllImport` attribute, you will not be able to use it.  Cosmos does not support any P/Invoke operations.  Anything used in a Cosmos OS must be written in a .NET language, not natively.